# error connections would be exceeded: 300

Tags: php, aerospike

When i am trying to connect aerospike(PHP Client) then i am getting an error

```
object(Aerospike)#4 (2) {
    ["errorno":"Aerospike":private] =>
        int(-7) ["error":"Aerospike":private] => 
             string(59) "Max node BB93615E8270008 connections would be exceeded: 300"
}
```

Comment: That's not really a question. You want to give more information about your configuration, whether you're using the PHP or HHVM client? Are you using fastCGI? Is this a standalone daemon?

Answer (score 2):

The Aerospike client for PHP has a [constructor](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-php/blob/master/doc/aerospike_construct.md) config `max_threads` that by default is set to 300. The PHP client is built around the C client, and passes that configuration down to the C client instance. Error status code -7 is [AEROSPIKE_ERR_NO_MORE_CONNECTIONS](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-c/blob/master/src/include/aerospike/as_status.h#L50-L53). You could increase the `max_threads`.

However, I'm not sure is how you're getting this error. The non-ZTS PHP client is a single execution thread, and those connections should be reused. It's really only an issue in multi-threaded environments like HHVM, Java, C, etc when multiple commands are executing in parallel. Please give more information about your code and environment.